# Windows 7 Edition-Specific Tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There's a couple tags currently out there with <10 posts each, and I'm wondering if they're actually necessary:

[windows-7-home-premium](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7-home-premium) and [windows-7-professional](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7-professional)

While I'm aware that there are some feature differences between editions, the underlying functionality of the OS generally remains the same.  I've also not seen any comparable tags for XP or Vista.  Should these just be rolled into the [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree, they should be rolled into the [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) tag...

The tags [windows-7-home-premium](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7-home-premium) and [windows-7-professional](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7-professional) are too limited in scope to have their own tags (and wikis, etc).